# proper way to use mongodb in multi-threading application

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I have server application with cron task (in own threads) and I want to insert data to mongodb database and I  wants to avoid deadlock or other multi-threading issues.

my code:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from pymongo import MongoClient
import sched
import time

TIME_INTERVAL = 3
THREAD_NUMBER = 4

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
pool = ThreadPool(THREAD_NUMBER)

websites = [
    "website1",
    "website2",
    "website3",
    "website4",
]

def insert_to_mongo(result):
    #that is proper way ?
    mongo_client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    dic = mongo_client["cjgs"]["tracks"]
    dic.insert({"Result": result})

def parsing_site(station):
    print "Doing stuff for ", station
    insert_to_mongo("Result for " + station)

def recursion(sc, station):
    parsing_site(station)
    sc.enter(TIME_INTERVAL, 1, recursion, (sc, station,))

def run_cron_task(station):
    s.enter(TIME_INTERVAL, 1, recursion, (s, station,))
    s.run()

pool.map(run_cron_task, websites)
```

how to use mongodb in this case ? how to write this code in a more python style way with decorators and other syntactic sugar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorators to encapsulate all threading stuff into it, like so:

```
def your_decorator(fun):
    # your threading stuff with fun

@decorator
def you_fun():
   # etc
```

But I would recommend you to rather take a look at [Two Phase Commit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/), which is recommended by MongoDB itself.